# How to use loop to create Bootstrap togglable in Pug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bootstrap-4, pug, bootstrap-tabs

Here's my code

```
div
    ul.nav.nav-tabs(role='tablist')
            //- li.active(role='presentation')
            //-     a(href='#session1', aria-controls='session1', role='tab', data-toggle='tab') Session 1
            //- li(role='presentation')
            //-     a(href='#session2', aria-controls='session2', role='tab', data-toggle='tab') Session 2
            //- li(role='presentation')
            //-     a(href='#session3', aria-controls='session3', role='tab', data-toggle='tab') Session 3
            //- li(role='presentation')
            //-     a(href='#session4', aria-controls='session4', role='tab', data-toggle='tab') Session 4
            each num in !{sessionsNumber}
                li(role='presentation')
                    a(href='#session' + num, aria-controls='session' + num, role='tab', data-toggle='tab') Session #{num};
    .tab-content
            #session1.tab-pane.active(role='tabpanel')
                table#myTable1.table.table-striped.table-bordered(cellspacing="0" width="100%")
            #session2.tab-pane(role='tabpanel')
                table#myTable2.table.table-striped.table-bordered(cellspacing="0" width="100%")
            #session3.tab-pane(role='tabpanel')
                table#myTable3.table.table-striped.table-bordered(cellspacing="0" width="100%")
            #session4.tab-pane(role='tabpanel')
                table#myTable4.table.table-striped.table-bordered(cellspacing="0" width="100%")
```

The part that I comment out worked as expect. But I want to change it to a loop. The !{sessionNumber} is what I render at express backend here.

```
 res.render('schedule', { sessionsNumber: JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4])})
```

I have console.log the !{sessionsNumber} in one of the script tag with document.reay and it shows it as an array as expected.
I am just not sure why it's not working when I changed it to a each loop. I also inspected the page and there's no html component under the ul tag.

Any help will be appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

`res.render('schedule', { sessionsNumber: JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4])})` is sending the array as a string to the view because you're json.stringifying it. That's not necessary.
Try instead to just send the array like so
`res.render('schedule', { sessionsNumber: [1,2,3,4]})`
then iterate it with

```
each num in sessionsNumber
 li(role='presentation')
   a(href='#session' + num, aria-controls='session' + num, role='tab', data-toggle='tab') Session #{num}
```

Comment: Already tried this and got the same result.
The reason I changed it to stringifying is because I only get 1 2 3 4 as number without stringifying it.
But after change it to stringifying, I got an array when I console.log it in the document.ready script tag.